# JQuery Datatables plugin - aoData, where it comes from and how

Tags: jquery, datatables

Looking at the "fnServerCallback" function parameter when initialising a Datatable, is there a way to know or set the "aoData" variable? Where is this variable set? Can I change the "name" attribute inside the array of objects?

I am asking this because knowing how aoData is set might prove useful when trying to pass data to a server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get access to aoData at any time by using fnSettings() (you can check its description [here](http://www.datatables.net/api)) function. Inside returned settings there is **aoData** object ready for you.

```
var oTable;
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
    var oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();

    /* Show an example parameter from the settings */
    alert( oSettings.aoData );
} );
```

Comment: So this allows me to change the aoData property inside the DataTable object?

Answer (score 1):

What exactly do you need to do?If you need to pass additional data to a server you can look at [this](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/custom_vars.html) example

EDIT - i found out this:

1. aoData is a name / value array of variables which jQuery will take and send to the server, so you can read them as POST (or GET if you elect to use that) variables.
2. You have "name" and "value" parameters defined twice in the same object... Try:

   aoData.push( { "name": "blah", "value": "blahblah" } );
      aoData.push( { "name": "thing", "value": "thingsvalue" } );

Comment: So that means that I have to manually get values from the table then? I outputted aoData and I see that it has some variables related to sorting, regex, etc. Are these not manually set? Are these set using a function somewhere?

Comment: I think that those variables comes from the options you chose when you setup the table, but i'm not 100% certain about it

Comment: "I think that those variables comes from the options you chose when you setup the table, but i'm not 100% certain about it" <-- Yes this is correct but what I want is for the ability to change them after initialization.

Comment: As i stated in my answer you should use aoData.